# How to validate expire date of iOS subscription IAPs correctly?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, itunes, subscription

I am dealing with iOS auto-renewable in app purchases.

After user purchases the item, and validating the receipt from

`App -> My server -> Apple's server -> My server -> App`

We'll get a bunch of data containing the info's about the purchase.

One of the field in those data is `expires_date_ms` which represents that when will this item expires.

The first idea that comes into my mind is to save the receipt data locally on user's device, and every time user launches the app,

I'll compare the expire date with `[NSDate date]`, if `[NSDate date]` is greater than expire date, this means that the item has expired.

However, I'm thinking about that if user changes the device's date, then they'll be able to use the item forever, because I'm comparing the expire date to `[NSDate date]` which represents users device date time.

The other thought that comes into my mind to fix this, is to validate the receipt with my server when the app launches, then, my server will return a field such as `is_expired` to ensure that the date will always be correct when checking the expire date.

Is this right of handling the expire date of IAP?

If not, how would be the best the handle this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: In my case, the receipt is saved in server and validate it periodically, then return the `is_expired` field to client